# PHP Laravel - HTML Forms array of values

Tags: php, html, laravel

I have the following form, with fields:

- From
- To
- Price

You can add multiple rows and this data is then sent to the controller.

What I want is:

Let's assume there are two rows of inputs currently on the page, the output would therefore be something like:

```
$rates => array(2)
   0 => [ 
      "from" => 1, 
      "to"   => 2,
      "price" => 10
   ], 
   1 => [ 
      "from" => 1, 
      "to"   => 2,
      "price" => 10
   ]
```

I have tried to do the following (HMTL):

```
  <input type="text" name="rates[]" placeholder="Enter rate from" 
  autocomplete="off" class="form-control">
```

But this just gives me an array of 6 with all the values, with no way of knowing the order. I have also tried the following:

```
<input type="text" name="rates[]['from']" placeholder="Enter rate from" 
      autocomplete="off" class="form-control">

 <input type="text" name="rates[]['to']" placeholder="Enter rate to" 
      autocomplete="off" class="form-control">

 <input type="text" name="rates[]['price']" placeholder="Enter rate price" 
      autocomplete="off" class="form-control">
```

This isn't producing the result(s) that I need. Is it possible to do what I want to do using HTML and PHP?

Comment: this you try `rates[index]['from']`

Comment: @HoàngĐăng Would `index` be a number?

Comment: yes, you can generate more input field by js

Comment: <input type="text" name="rates[0]['from']" placeholder="Enter rate from" 
      autocomplete="off" class="form-control">

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of using an index-based approach, you can use three different arrays (`from`, `to` and `prices` e.g.). You can then iterate through all of them to get your values.

### HTML

```
<input type="text" name="from[]" placeholder="Enter rate from" 
      autocomplete="off" class="form-control">

 <input type="text" name="to[]" placeholder="Enter rate to" 
      autocomplete="off" class="form-control">

 <input type="text" name="prices[]" placeholder="Enter rate price" 
      autocomplete="off" class="form-control">
```

### PHP

```
 $from = [
        'Jane',
        'Bob',
        'Mary',
    ];
    $to = [
        'John',
        'Alex',
        'Paul',
    ];
    $prices = [
        10,
        2500,
        2,
    ];

  $finalValues = [];
  foreach ($prices as $i => $price) {
    $finalValues[
              "from" => $from[i];
              "to" => $to[i];
              "price" => $price;
  }
```

This only works when your values are all required or give back null when not set